# Basic chaining method is returning object of class error

Tags: php

I am trying to create a simple chainged getter/setter. So I can access it like so:

```
// initiate class
$testModel = new TestModel();

// setters
$testModel
    ->setUser("Hello")
    ->setEmail("Test@gmail.com");

// getters
$testModel
    ->getUser()
    ->getEmail();
```

When I vardump I get the following:

```
object(Filtration\Model\TestModel)#5 (2) { ["User"]=> string(5) "Hello" ["Email"]=> string(14) "Test@gmail.com" }
```

But when I echo the `getters` so I can have it print out on my screen I get:
    Catchable fatal error: Object of class Filtration\Model\TestModel could not be converted to string in

My getter/setter class:

```
Class TestModel
{

    /**
     * [description here]
     *
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function getUser() {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * [Description]
     *
     * @param [type] $newUser [description]
     */
    public function setUser($User) {
        $this->User = $User;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * [description here]
     *
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function getUsername() {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * [Description]
     *
     * @param [type] $newUsername [description]
     */
    public function setUsername($Username) {
        $this->Username = $Username;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * [description here]
     *
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function getEmail() {
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * [Description]
     *
     * @param [type] $newEmail [description]
     */
    public function setEmail($Email) {
        $this->Email = $Email;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * [description here]
     *
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function getFirstname() {
        return $this->Firstname;
    }

    /**
     * [Description]
     *
     * @param [type] $newFirstname [description]
     */
    public function setFirstname($Firstname) {
        $this->Firstname = $Firstname;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you _var_dumping_ ? and when you say "_when I echo the getters_" , exactly what variable are you echoing?

Comment: Most of your getters just return `$this`, rather than the specific property in question. `getFirstName` seems like it should work properly.

Comment: I'm not sure I see the point of chaining getters.

Comment: I suppose you could echo the property in the getter methods and return `$this` so that they could be chained, but anyone else who might ever work on your project will _not_ expect a getter to work that way.

Comment: I tried returning the object inside the getter, but get the following: 
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getEmail() on string

Comment: There is no point in chaining getters. The whole point of getters is to return the value of a private/protected property. That means it returns a string, an array, whatever type your property is - but the method is **not** chainable.

Comment: It makes no sense to return the object from a getter. A getter is supposed to return the property you're asking for, not the object.

Comment: Do you really think it makes sense that `getUser` and `getEmail` do exactly the same thing?

Comment: getUser was supposed to reference the user's ID

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getters should not be chainable, because they need to return the referenced value. Setters can be chainable. By returning `$this` in a getter, you cannot pass the actual value requested by the getter method, which makes the getter kind of pointless.

I would update the class something like this:

```
Class TestModel
{
    private $User;
    private $Username;
    private $Email;
    private $Firstname;

    /**
     * [description here]
     *
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function getUser() {
        return $this->User;
    }

    /**
     * [Description]
     *
     * @param [type] $newUser [description]
     */
    public function setUser($User) {
        $this->User = $User;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * [description here]
     *
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function getUsername() {
        return $this->Username;
    }

    /**
     * [Description]
     *
     * @param [type] $newUsername [description]
     */
    public function setUsername($Username) {
        $this->Username = $Username;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * [description here]
     *
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function getEmail() {
        return $this->Email;
    }

    /**
     * [Description]
     *
     * @param [type] $newEmail [description]
     */
    public function setEmail($Email) {
        $this->Email = $Email;

        return $this;
    }


    /**
     * [description here]
     *
     * @return [type] [description]
     */
    public function getFirstname() {
        return $this->Firstname;
    }

    /**
     * [Description]
     *
     * @param [type] $newFirstname [description]
     */
    public function setFirstname($Firstname) {
        $this->Firstname = $Firstname;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

And then make use of it as such:

```
$testModel = new TestModel();

// setters
$testModel
    ->setUser("Hello")
    ->setEmail("Test@gmail.com");

// getters
echo $testModel->getUser();
echo $testModel->getEmail();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want method chaning you must return `$this` in each getter/setter. Therefore

```
echo $testModel->setEmail('foo')->setName('bar');
```

is, basically, echoing an object. You could define `__toString` magic method in your object, so it can be echoed:

```
class TestModel
{
    protected $email;

    protected $name;

    // getters & setters

    // Should always return string
    public function __toString()
    {
        return 'Hey, I'm a string representation of the object! My email is '.$email' and name is '.$name;
    }
}
```

However, if you want to achieve some sort of concatenation via getters chaining - this would not be possible.

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it. The problem is that you're not returning the right information when calling some of your getter methods. For example `getEmail()` should return `$this->email` not `$this`.

This is how I would structure your class:

```
Class UserModel
{
    private $name;
    private $email;

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

And this is how I would use it:

```
$user1 = new UserModel();

// setter
$user1
    ->setName("John")
    ->setEmail("john@gmail.com");

// Shows all the user's information
var_dump($user1);

// Shows specific details of that user (EMAIL)
var_dump($user1->getEmail());

// Shows specific details of that user (NAME)
var_dump($user1->getName());
```

---

**ANOTHER WAY OF DOING IT**

Don't feel constrained with doing it one way. There are multiple ways to achieve the same result. It depends on how you plan on using it. This is an alternative:

```
Class UserModel
{
    private $name;
    private $email;

    public function __construct($args)
    {
        $this->name = $args["name"];
        $this->email = $args["email"];
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }
}
```

to use:

```
$data = [
    "name" => "John",
    "email" => "john@gmail.com",
];

// initiate class
$user1 = new UserModel($data);

// Shows all the user's information
var_dump($user1);

// Shows specific details of that user (EMAIL)
var_dump($user1->getEmail());

// Shows specific details of that user (NAME)
var_dump($user1->getName());
```